# Hello, any idea why I get an error on initiating React "react-scripts" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs

PS C:\Users\cdpab\OneDrive\Escritorio\ASSIGMENTS\Web Development cw2\CoffeeReact-main> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> coffee-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\OneDrive\Escritorio\ASSIGMENTS\CoffeeReact-main>

Answer (score 0):

Try npm install --global react-scripts and then react-scripts start. If that doesn't work, try npx react-scripts start.